# Google Analytics - Email Tracking links click - How to see ALL custom campaign data ("send", "open", "click" ) in the same view

Tags: email, google-analytics, event-tracking

I want to implements the [Google Analytics Email Tracking Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email) like explain in the doc.

- I send an event with campaign parameters for email "send" action
- I send an event with campaign parameters for email "open" action, by placing an image tag within the email
- And I add custom campaign parameters to links that I want to track for click in this email

**However, I don't find the way to see ALL those custom-campaign data in ONE Google Analytics view.**

Like describe [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?visit_id=636735440720097296-1338846714&rd=1&hl=en#data), I go to *Acquisition > Campaign* view, then I select my custom campaign, but:

- "send", "open" are set in Event action (which is not set for a link click)
- link click can be found use "campaign content" (which is not set for "send/open" events)

But this requires separate searches, which are based on assumptions...

Maybe I'm wrong...
Did I miss something?

---

#### Screenshots

[image: Campaign root]

[image: Campaign + Action event dimension]

[image: Campaign + Campaign content dimension]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en) using the "Flat Table" type with campaign, source/medium, content, event action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I tried. 
Except that including the both columns "Event action" and "Content" seems to reduce the results list...
**The rows having not "Event action" (ie. `(not set)`) are hidden.** But the [setup of "Links Clicks Tracking"](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033863?hl=en#parameters) doesn't have parameters to set value for "Event action".
I guess it's because "Event action" is a _required_ data...

Comment: Yes Event action is required, if you're not sending event action, then you should look into configuring that. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events